# Why are not mayors terms limited as for the presidents? (especially in developing countries)

Tags: election

Checking [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_term_limits), I have noticed that the vast majority of countries do not limit mayors terms count. However, the president is usually limited to two terms of 4-5 years.

To narrow the question scope, I will take the particular example of my native country, Romania: ex-communist country, parliamentary democracy within the European Union. However, I think the following reasoning can be applied to many other developing countries as well:

- **relatively high corruption levels** ([source](http://www.transparency.org/cpi2012/results)) clearly helps mayors to maintain their power, as they (directly or not) control much of the economy within the town they lead
- **parliamentary or presidential elections disruption** - mayors of medium and small towns or villages can easily influence voting by using local resources to promote friendly candidates. In the country side this done through relations with some other public figures such as priests or medical doctors.
- **one round-system for voting for mayors** as opposed to [Two-round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-round_system) one (might be Romania specific) clearly favored existing mayors. This has practically rendered mayor election useless (most of existing mayors have won an extra term)

The bias towards having the same mayors is so big that some mayors were in jail when they were elected.

**Question:** considering all above, why can mayors be elected for more than the typically two terms? (while presidents can not)

Comment: This is just a theory, but in smaller communities you might run out of mayors when you have term limits. In my hometown (which isn't even that small with 75k inhabitants) the current mayor ran unopposed in the last election. Not because he somehow suppresses the opposition (it's Germany. Elected politicians are rather nonviolent here) but simply because nobody else wanted the job.

Comment: @Philipp - your argument is plausible. However, Germany is an advanced democracy where corruption level is low (place 13 within the provided link). (also, just a theory) I think that "getting elected" appetite is lower within developed countries.

Comment: @Alexei Being the mayor of a small town doesn't tend to have a lot of upward mobility politically, so you won't have many aspiring politicians trying to gain fame by taking the position (compare that to the mayor of e.g. Bucharest, whose policies probably at least get some media attention).  Taking away the option to remain mayor as a career may reduce the number of candidates further.

Comment: \*cough\* [Bloomberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_mayoral_election,_2009) \*cough\* NYC \*cough\*

Comment: In many countries there are no limits on the terms of the head of the executive.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian - while that is true, a mayor does not have to disappear from the political picture of a town. He/she can be a member of a City Council a still pull some strings. Since we are talking about a developing country, money alone can be a incentive to run for elections (the absolute minimum salary of a mayor is more than the national average), so there is a small chance of running out of candidates :).

Comment: @JamesK - That is true. However (if I am not mistaken) within the parliamentary democracies, the whole executive (including the head) are at the mercy of the Parliament which usually validates it. I am curious about a top of governments lifespan, but cannot find one.

Comment: Term limits for mayors are fairly common.

Comment: First, term limits are not universal (and when enacted, they must be more than two), but your question seems to imply that they are. Also, one important issue is how many powers mayors have. I don't know for other countries, in mine they do not control electoral organization (they cannot even shorten their term), cannot apoint (or influence the appointment of judges), rule is shared with a council. There is room for corruption and misdeeds, but not to a point that threatens the democratic process (and if they get close to that, central government can depose them)

Comment: @SJuan76 Good point. In cities with a council-manager form of government, the mayor is often just the title of the chairman of the city council. Strong mayor cities are the exception rather than the norm.

Comment: @user4012 \*cough\* not a small town \*cough\*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important factor is that while there are many large municipalities in the world, the vast majority of municipalities in every country have low populations (often under 5,000) and even more so in less developed countries than in highly developed countries, the supply of people who have the skill set necessary to be a top manager of a governmental organization (that will often be the largest single employer in its boundaries) is pretty small. So, when people find someone who does a good job they don't want to arbitrarily remove them, especially if no one else is seriously interested in contesting the post in a small community.

Also, in municipalities, and especially small ones, it is far hard to suppress information about how well the local government is being managed. People can see whether the municipality is running well or not with their own eyes. It is hard to hide incompetence.

Comment: That's a good explanation. However, regarding the last paragraph: in my native country (Romania), in many villages or even small towns, some mayors had more than 4 terms and are far from being competent. Everybody knows that they decide almost everything important there (usually through approvals required from the Town Hall). Some of them even missed the first days of their terms, because they were in jail. Of course, this is corruption related and maybe the limitation would make sense in such a context.

Comment: Why does no one run against or defeat the compromised incumbent? Are the elections themselves corrupt? Are people promised favors if they vote for the incumbent? Are there threats against challengers? Are there no higher authorities that can prosecute corruption? Corruption is usually a symptom of something else that is broken more than it is a true cause of a political outcome by itself.

Comment: There are candidates, but incumbents usually rely on various tricks: offer small gifts to the people, use local important figures like priests and medical doctors to promote them etc. Corruption is [prosecuted](http://www.romaniajournal.ro/eu-praises-romania-scolds-bulgaria-keeps-monitoring-on-both/), but the process is rather slow and has lots of opponents. Electoral fraud exists (some dead people voted from time to tome) and the main opposition party leader was convicted for it, but it is considered too small to influence the final result.

Comment: Why would term limits change anything? Presumably the old mayor could find someone to be a front man for him if he is that powerful.